# Word wrap for a label in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, label, controls

How can one get word wrap functionality for a `Label` for text which goes out of bounds?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

The quick answer: switch **off** [AutoSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

The big problem here is that the label will not change its height automatically (only width). To get this right you will need to subclass the label and include vertical resize logic.

Basically what you need to do in OnPaint is:

1. Measure the height of the text (Graphics.MeasureString).
2. If the label height is not equal to the height of the text set the height and return.
3. Draw the text.

You will also need to set the [ResizeRedraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resizeredraw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) style flag in the constructor.

Comment: Select the label you're dynamically adding text to. Look at the properties for the label and turn off AutoSize.  You will now be able to drag/set the area for the label and it will automatically auto-wrap to stay within those parameters.  No need for any additional coding.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for as it pertains to formatting my form with explanatory text that is in a paragraph form.

Comment: @madeFromCode You'd need to set the height programmatically if you want the label to expand vertically else your text will be clipped.

Answer (score 395):

Actually, the accepted answer is unnecessarily complicated.

If you set the label to AutoSize, it will automatically grow with whatever text you put in it.  (This includes vertical growth.)

If you want to make it word wrap at a particular width, you can set the MaximumSize property.

```
myLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 0);
myLabel.AutoSize = true;
```

Tested and works.

Comment: If you have the label snap into it's container, you can switch off AutoSize, leave the max size property as it is, and it will word-wrap exactly as we want. KISS at work!

Comment: You can not achieve a fluid width with that solution.

Comment: @Sam: Yes you can, you just set the proper "anchor" properties.  Have you even tried it?

Comment: @JohnGietzen I did. Probably we are not talking about the same. I've a label and a panel below this label. Everything should be fluid in width. I want that the panels top is always positioned on the labels bottom. I

Comment: Sam: you should be able to set the `Dock` property of both the label and panel to `Top`, instead of my solution.

Comment: I have latched on to `OnResize` in the parent and call `myLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(Bounds.Width, 0);`

Comment: My label doen't have the AutoSize and MaximumSize properties, how can I add these properties ?

Comment: This is working to great effect for me in combination with a TableLayoutPanel and resetting the MaximumSize on Resize of the parent container with a combination of AutoSize and Percentage rows. It seems like the simplest solution for auto-wrapping width-filling auto-height labels.

Comment: @BengiBesçeli For anyone seeing this and wondering how: you can just type "label1.AutoSize = true" even if it doesn't auto complete.

Answer (score 29):

In my case (label on a panel) I set `label.AutoSize = false` and `label.Dock = Fill`.
And the label text is wrapped automatically.

Comment: This makes the label fill the entire form and make it obscure all other controls in the form... That is, it does not seem to work. Are there other requirements such that it will not fill the entire form?

Comment: the label **is on a panel**, not on the form directly. Therefore the text does not exceed the bounds of the panel

Comment: OK, but then wouldn't it obscure all other controls in the panel?

Comment: What prevents you from creating an extra panel containing only the label?

Comment: That seems like some extra layout that should be unnecessary. Surely the label should have its own box rather than needing to be put into another box.

Comment: @Edwin - just fyi _"Surely the label should have its own box rather than needing to be put into another box"_ - in other words, a container, which is what a `Panel` is (among other containers).

Answer (score 24):

There is no autowrap property but this can be done programmatically to size it dynamically. Here is one solution:

- Select the properties of the label
- `AutoSize` = `True`
- `MaximumSize` = (*Width*, *Height*) where *Width* = max size you want the label to be and *Height* = how many pixels you want it to wrap

  [image: Sample Properties]

Comment: One more note, if you leave the maximum height at 0, it will continue to expand vertically.

Comment: My label doen't have the AutoSize and MaximumSize properties, how can I add these ?

Answer (score 13):

From [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network), *[Automatically Wrap Text in Label](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/97c18a1d-729e-4a68-8223-0fcc9ab9012b)*:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class GrowLabel : Label {
    private bool mGrowing;
    public GrowLabel() {
        this.AutoSize = false;
    }
    private void resizeLabel() {
        if (mGrowing) 
            return;
        try {
            mGrowing = true;
            Size sz = new Size(this.Width, Int32.MaxValue);
            sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font, sz, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
            this.Height = sz.Height;
        }
        finally {
            mGrowing = false;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        resizeLabel();
    }
    protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnFontChanged(e);
        resizeLabel();
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        resizeLabel();
    }
}
```

Comment: In order to break on characters rather than words (useful when you have long strings without spaces such as file paths), use (TextFormatFlags.WordBreak | TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl) instead. See the last post in the same MSDN thread.

Comment: Also, don't forget to include label's top and bottom padding in the calculation (`Height = sz.Height + Padding.Vertical;`)

Answer (score 8):

I had to find a quick solution, so I just used a TextBox with those properties:

```
var myLabel = new TextBox
                    {
                        Text = "xxx xxx xxx",
                        WordWrap = true,
                        AutoSize = false,
                        Enabled = false,
                        Size = new Size(60, 30),
                        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None,
                        Multiline =  true,
                        BackColor =  container.BackColor
                    };
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but I might prefer using ReadOnly to setting Enabled to false.

Comment: This is an imaginative solution that also works well on Compact Framework (where Label does not have AutoSize and MaximumSize properties).

Answer (score 3):

Have a better one based on @hypo 's answer

```
public class GrowLabel : Label {
    private bool mGrowing;
    public GrowLabel() {
        this.AutoSize = false;
    }
    private void resizeLabel() {
        if (mGrowing)
            return;
        try {
            mGrowing = true;
            int width = this.Parent == null ? this.Width : this.Parent.Width;

            Size sz = new Size(this.Width, Int32.MaxValue);
            sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font, sz, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
            this.Height = sz.Height + Padding.Bottom + Padding.Top;
        } finally {
            mGrowing = false;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
        resizeLabel();
    }
    protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnFontChanged(e);
        resizeLabel();
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        resizeLabel();
    }
}
```

`int width = this.Parent == null ? this.Width : this.Parent.Width;` this allows you to use auto-grow label when docked to a parent, e.g. a panel.

`this.Height = sz.Height + Padding.Bottom + Padding.Top;` here we take care of padding for top and bottom.

Answer (score 2):

1. Put the label inside a panel
2. Handle the `ClientSizeChanged event` for the panel, making the
   label fill the space:

   ```
   private void Panel2_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       label1.MaximumSize = new Size((sender as Control).ClientSize.Width - label1.Left, 10000);
   }
   ```
3. Set `Auto-Size` for the label to `true`
4. Set `Dock` for the label to `Fill`

All but step 2 would typically be done in the designer window.

Comment: Are steps 3 and 4 done in the designer? Any reason why they are step 3 and 4?

Comment: They are done in the designer (but could be done in code if you need it to) and there's no reason for the order.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it will fit all use-cases but I often use a simple trick to get the wrapping behaviour:
put your `Label` with `AutoSize=false` inside a 1x1 `TableLayoutPanel` which will take care of the `Label`'s size.

Answer (score 1):

Set the AutoEllipsis Property to 'TRUE' and AutoSize Property to 'FALSE'.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend setting `AutoEllipsis` property of label to `true` and `AutoSize` to `false`. If text length exceeds label bounds, it'll add three dots `(...)` at the end and automatically set the complete text as a tooltip. So users can see the complete text by hovering over the label.

Answer (score 0):

If your panel is limiting the width of your label, you can set your label’s Anchor property to Left, Right and set AutoSize to true. This is conceptually similar to listening for the Panel’s `SizeChanged` event and updating the label’s MaximumSize to a `new Size(((Control)sender).Size.Width, 0)` as suggested by [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680595/429091). Every side listed in the Anchor property is, well, anchored to the containing Control’s respective inner side. So listing two opposite sides in Anchor effectively sets the control’s dimension. Anchoring to Left and Right sets the Control’s Width property and Anchoring to Top and Bottom would set its Height property.

This solution, as C#:

```
label.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
label.AutoSize = true;
```

Comment: Doesn't work. The Label increases the width of my panel just that it doesn't have to wrap. Unfortunately, the window is not as wide.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to set the label width independent of the content, I find that the easiest way is this:

- Set autosize true
- Set maximum width to how you want it
- Set minimum width identically

Now the label is of constant width, but it adapts its height automatically.

Then for dynamic text, decrease the font size. If necessary, use this snippet in the sub where the label text is set:

```
If Me.Size.Height - (Label12.Location.Y + Label12.Height) < 20 Then
    Dim naam As String = Label12.Font.Name
    Dim size As Single = Label12.Font.SizeInPoints - 1
    Label12.Font = New Font(naam, size)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me in my Form called InpitWindow:
In Designer for Label:

```
AutoSize = true;
Achors = Top, Left, Right.

private void InputWindow_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    lbCaption.MaximumSize = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width - btOK.Width - btOK.Margin.Left - btOK.Margin.Right -
        lbCaption.Margin.Right - lbCaption.Margin.Left, 
        Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height / 2);
    this.Height = this.Height + (lbCaption.Height - btOK.Height - btCancel.Height);
    //Uncomment this line to prevent form height chage to values lower than initial height
    //this.MinimumSize = new Size(this.MinimumSize.Width, this.Height);
}
//Use this handler if you want your label change it size according to form clientsize.
private void InputWindow_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    lbCaption.MaximumSize = new Size(this.ClientSize.Width - btOK.Width - btOK.Margin.Left * 2 - btOK.Margin.Right * 2 -
        lbCaption.Margin.Right * 2 - lbCaption.Margin.Left * 2,
        Screen.GetWorkingArea(this).Height / 2);
}
```

[Whole code of my form](https://db.tt/b39Ndi0M)

Answer (score 0):

If the dimensions of the button need to be kept unchanged:

```
myButton.Text = "word\r\nwrapped"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer for this problem is to change the DOCK property of the Label. It is "NONE" by default.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are entering text into the label beforehand, you can do this.

1. In the designer, 
   Right-Click on the label and click Properties.
2. In Properties, search for text tab.
3. Click in the tab and click on the arrow button next to it.
4. A box will popup on top of it.
5. You can press enter in the popup box to add lines and type as in notepad!
   (PRESS ENTER WHERE YOU WANT TO WRAP THE LABEL TEXT)

Answer (score 0):

I have a label that autowraps and grows to whatever size in a right docked autosize panel, whose width is set by other content.

Label (in tablelayoutpanel) Autosize = True.

TableLayoutPanel (in panel) Autosize = True, AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink, Dock = Bottom, one Column SizeType = 100%, one Row SizeType = 100%.

Panel (right docked in form) AutoSize = True, AutoSizeMode = GrowAndShrink, Dock = Right.

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel instead of Label and set the property LinkArea as below.

```
myLabel.LinkArea = new LinkArea(0, 0);
```

Answer (score -12):

Use `style="overflow:Scroll"` in the label as in the below HTML. This will add the scroll bar in the label within the panel.

```
<asp:Label
    ID="txtAOI"
    runat="server"
    style="overflow:Scroll"
    CssClass="areatext"
    BackColor="White"
    BorderColor="Gray"
    BorderWidth="1"
    Width = "900" ></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Voting this down is fine, but at least say why you did it. The reason this was voted down is because an <asp:Label> is not used in WinForms. This answer is for the wrong platform.

Comment: because it is asp.net not winform