# How to set a text of label box dynamically in C#4.0 with word Wrap functionality?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, label

In my C#4.0 Windows Forms Based Application, i having one Label box.Now i want to dynamically set the text of the label box.My text looks like paragraph's.So, Whenever i displayed my text, only part of the text are shown in the form with one line.So, I want to wrap the text to next line whenever it reaches the forms right end...

how i do it.Please Guide me to get out of this issue...

Comment: See this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-label-in-winforms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need to do is set the label control's [`AutoSize` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize.aspx) to False. You can do this either in the designer via the Properties window, or through code: `myLabel.AutoSize = false`

It is turned on by default when you add the control in the designer (though the default value is false when you instantiate the control through code). With this property on, the control tries to automatically adjust its *width* (and not its height!) to display its entire contents. This doesn't work out so well with multiple paragraphs, as it's impossible to fit the entire contents in a single line on the screen.

By turning this property off, you can manually resize the control to accommodate your text.

Everything else is handled automatically. The text will automatically wrap to a new line when it reaches the edge of the control's border. For example:

[image: The asker's original question, displayed on a label control with AutoSize = false.]

If you don't want to manually set the size of the label control, you can take advantage of the [`Dock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock.aspx) and [`Anchor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx) properties, which will automatically resize the control to its parent container. This is convenient, say, if you want the label to fill the entire form or panel that you've placed it inside.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you set `label.AutoSize = true;` and set a fixed with for your label. It will automatically word-wrap for you:

```
label.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 0);
```

This is the easiest solution that I know. Just tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1):

In the Label's properties, unset the `AutoSize` property (set to False), then anchor the Label as required. This should have the effect you're looking for.