# label inside a panel in winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working in a winform where I created a label in a panel. As I append text words, how do I cause the label to go to the next line when the text fills the width of the panel?

I tried the following code but it doesn't look right

```
        int lbl= 150;
        if (Lbl_full_list.Width > o)
        {
            my_Lbl.Text += "\n" + comboBox1.Text;
            o += 150;
        }
        else
        {
             my_Lbl.Text.Text += " , " + comboBox1.Text;
        }
```

Comment: Here is a similar thread.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-label-in-winforms

Comment: I saw this before and was not successful when I tried it. Could you please show me an example? Thank you!

Comment: @naf-naf just checked the thread (posted above) scroll a bit down  there. look at the answer with most votes. `MaximumSize` property is a way to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to:

1. Set `my_Lbl.AutoSize` to `false`.
2. Set the docking mode of `my_Lbl` in the containing panel to `Fill`.

Now `my_Lbl` will automatically start a new row when a line of text exceeds the label's width. Plus you get dynamic layout when the containing `Panel` resizes.

Note that you should create a dedicated `Panel` for this purpose. If you have more `Controls` inside the containing `Panel` you are currently using just create a new one only for this purpose (containing `my_Lbl`).

Answer (score 0):

There is `MaximumSize (Width, Height)` property. set it according to the needs. Also leave the `autosize` to be `true`.