# Auto adjust Label Text as I move splitter

Tags: c#, winforms, width, label, splitcontainer

[image]

As I move splitter to left, it hide my text(as in above image). I want to auto adjust Label Text as I move splitter.

update me!

Comment: So you are looking to refresh the label text when the splitter is moving?

Comment: where is hidden text? on left?

Comment: @reniuz hidden text is on right side

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the lb.Anchor property, info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor.aspx)

it should be something like

```
lb.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```

or similar depending where you want it to anchor

Comment: if your problem is lack of word-wrapping this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-label-in-winforms, if not use another control instead of a label (as a disabled richtexteditor)