# Adding new property to a .NET control

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-3.0

I am trying to add a new property to existing label .NET control, like AutoSize(existing label property),

something like IsWordWrap(new custom property)=true. (so that the words can auto wrap)

Any thoughts? so that i can give LabelName.IsWordWrap=true;

Textbox has wordwrap propery, is there any way i can inherit that to label, by any means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would derive a new class from `Label` and add the logic you require.  It would be much easier to simply style a `TextBox` to look like a label though.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
// ...

class WrappingLabel : Label
{
    private bool _isWordWrap
    public bool IsWordWrap
    {
        get { return _isWordWrap; }
        set 
        {
            if( _isWordWrap != value )
            {
                _isWordWrap = value;                    
                FormatText( value );
            }
        }
    }

    private void FormatText( bool wrapped )
    {
        // logic to wrap or un-wrap text goes here.
        // you will need to call this when the text changes as well.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i agree with you on textbox, but can you please show a quick sample if you have for that derivation of new class and how to pin up the new property?

Comment: @Sharpeye500: Added an example.  I didn't actually implement the wrapping logic as I don't have time for that.  Still though... just use a TextBox.  You are wasting your time if you can get the look and behavior you want using a standard control (and you can).

Answer (score 1):

You could also check out the solution listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680595/360944) (there are a couple of other ones as well).