# multiline textbox auto adjust it's height according to the amount of text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox which can return various strings ranging from 5 characters upto 1000 characters in length. 
It has the following properties:

- multiline = true
- wordwrap = true

Which other properties of the textbox do I need to set to make the following possible?

- The width of the box should be fixed
- The height of the box to auto adjust depending on how much text it is returning e.g if the text runs onto 3 lines then it adjusts to 3 lines in height.

Comment: I don't see any `?` What is your question? Please don't write `how can I do that`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this following code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     private const int EM_GETLINECOUNT = 0xba;
     [DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
     private static extern int SendMessage(int hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);


     public Form1()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        var numberOfLines = SendMessage(textBox1.Handle.ToInt32(), EM_GETLINECOUNT, 0, 0);
        this.textBox1.Height = (textBox1.Font.Height + 2) * numberOfLines;
     }
}
```

Comment: If text box uses a custom font use `textBox1.Height = (textBox1.Font.Height + 2) * numberOfLines;`

Comment: ...would I have been better using a different control than the textbox? do any of the controls have this functionality built into their properties?

Comment: numberOflines = textbox1.lines.count();

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be any functionality to do this built in to the TextBox class, but the Font class has a [Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font.height.aspx) property that returns the number of pixels between baselines.

It is also possible to find out how many lines the text in the TextBox occupies, as described in [this](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/04/07/511.aspx) blog post (warning: it's not exactly elegant).

Once you've obtained this information, you should be able to make the TextChanged handler set the height of the TextBox accordingly using some simple maths.

Answer (score 3):

I can't believe there is still no really elegant way. This is what I puzzled out:

```
textBox.Height += textBox.GetPositionFromCharIndex(textBox.Text.Length - 1).Y 
    + 3 + textBox.Font.Height - textBox.ClientSize.Height;
```

This works by determining the pixel coordinates of the last character of the text.

You can execute this after setting the contents, i.e. in `OnLoad` of the `Form` or `OnTextChanged` of the `TextBox` control. If the fixed width changes when the user resizes the form, you should also take care of that, i.e. `OnResize` or `OnClientSizeChanged`.

`TextBox` supports the `AutoSize` property. However, it is already set to `true` by default, and it is not shown in the property editor or IntelliSense. It is just for font height changes and does not work when using `MultiLine = true` :( - this is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.autosize.aspx).

Other options might include using a different control, like `RichTextBox` or `Label`. I didn't try yet, but it seems that a [Label supports AutoSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680595) much better.

Answer (score 2):

```
private void tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tb.Height = (tb.Text.Split('\n').Length + 2 ) * tb.Font.Height;
}
```

Comment: now that the height is adjusting automatically the anchoring of to the form seem to be not working: the textbox is sometimes bigger than the form so I cannot see the bottom of the textbox. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the height of the text box from code. Count the number of lines ([this article here can help you with a way to do just that](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/04/07/511.aspx)), then set the `Textbox.Height` to the value you need (number of line * 8px or so, depending on the font used inside the `TextBox`).

In the linked article solution was to override TextBox control class to be able to get the number of lines; there might be other ways to get the number of lines, but the suggested solution in the article looks quite elegant to me.

Answer (score 1):

Add MaxHeight property on TextBox as below.

`<TextBox Name="txtSample" MaxHeight="1000" />`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this gives the height of the text as how it is drawn in the textbox itself:

```
SizeF MessageSize = MyTextBoxControl.CreateGraphics()
                                .MeasureString(MyTextBoxControl.Text,
                                                MyTextBoxControl.Font,
                                                MyTextBoxControl.Width, 
                                                new StringFormat(0));
```

I am not sure what `StringFormat` should be but the values `StringFormatFlags` do not seem to apply to a default `TextBox` make up.

Now with `MessageSize.Height` you know the height of the text in the textbox.