# Disable selecting text in a TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I have a textbox with the following (important) properties:

```
this.license.Multiline = true;
this.license.ReadOnly = true;
this.license.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
this.license.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
```

It looks like this:

[image: Textbox with highlighted text in it]

How can I disable the user to highlight text in this textbox (I do not want to disable the textbox completely)?

Comment: Will it have a vertical scrroll?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? What kind of `RichTextBox` is this?

Comment: @BigM `this.license.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;` - must be winforms

Answer (score 12):

Attach to the `SelectionChanged` event, and inside the event set `e.Handled = true;` and the `SelectionLength = 0;` and that will stop the selection from occuring. This is similar to what it takes to keep a key press from happening.

Comment: I couldn't find such event for the WinForms TextBox control.

Comment: @checho In case you're interested, I ran into the same issue as you but resolved it by using the WinForms RichTextBox control, which thankfully does have the `SelectionChanged` event.

Comment: Doing this with a TextBox results in an recursive loop and StackOverflowException. Changing the selection inside the SelectionChanged callback is a bad idea!

Comment: @floydheld You can unregister the hander right before the SelectionAll and again register it right after to prevent the StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 9):

If you put the text into a label and then put the label into a `System.Widnows.Forms.Panel` control that has `AutoScroll` turned on you can display the text w/o it being selectable.

Comment: A MUCH MUCH better solution. No hacks to make a text box work.

Comment: @pitersmx https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-a-label-in-windows-forms

Answer (score 8):

To disable selection highlight in a `TextBox`, you can override `WndProc` and handle [`WM_SETFOCUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646283(v=vs.85).aspx) message and replace it with a [`WM_KILLFOCUS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646282(v=vs.85).aspx). Please be aware that it doesn't make the `TextBox` control read-only and if you need to make it read-only, you should also set `ReadOnly` property to `true`. If you set `ReadOnly` to true, you can set and its `BackColor` to `White` or any other suitable color which you want.

In below code, I added a `SelectionHighlightEnabled` property to `MyTextBox` to make enabling or disabling the selection highlight easy:

- `SelectionHighlightEnabled`: Gets or sets a value indicating selection highlight is enabled or not. The value is `true` by default to act like a normal `TextBox`. If you set it to `false` then the selection highlight will not be rendered.

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        SelectionHighlightEnabled = true;
    }
    const int WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007;
    const int WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008;
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool SelectionHighlightEnabled { get; set; }
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_SETFOCUS && !SelectionHighlightEnabled)
            m.Msg = WM_KILLFOCUS;

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works well. You might also want to change the `Cursor` to Default (instead of the text selection IBeam pointer).

Comment: @intrepidis Thanks; makes sense. In addition, since it doesn't make the control read-only, if you need to make it read-only, you should also set ReadOnly property to true and also you may want to set BackColor to White in case of enabling read-only.

Comment: The input cursor disappeared for me

Answer (score 2):

I came across of this thread for my same issue I faced. Somehow I resolved it as below,

```
if (sender != null)
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    if((sender as TextBox).SelectionLength != 0)
                        (sender as TextBox).SelectionLength = 0;
                }
```

Verifying if the length changed other than 0, then only set it to 0, resolves the recursive loop.

Comment: in which event? the mousedown event doesn't have e.handled property...

Answer (score 2):

Very Easy Solution

Find a Label and into the textbox go to mousedown event and
set focus to the label

This is in VB and can be easily converted into C#

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.MouseDown
        Label1.Focus()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the standard TextBox doesn't have the SelectionChanged event, here's what I came up with.

```
private void TextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Comment: Also for a better solution, you can add events to clamchoda [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53607577/9819238) like: `MouseLeave` and `KeyPress`
MouseLeave for deselecting when the mouse is no longer in the textbox area and KeyPress is for deselecting when the user press the Shift + Key Up/Down for selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a disabled `RichTextBox` and reset the color to black afterwards.

```
RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
rtb.IsEnabled = false;
rtb.Text = "something";
rtb.SelectAll();
rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
rtb.SelectedText = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAML / WPF you should use a **TextBlock** instead of a **TextBox**.

**ONLY IF YOU USE A TEXTBOX AS A DISPLAY AND NOT FOR INPUT**
- as TextBlock makes it seem as if the text is "engraved" onto the form itself, and not within a textbox. To get a Border around the TextBlock (if you wish), you can either do it :

In *XAML* such as :

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray">
    <TextBlock Background="White" Text="Your Own TextBlock"/>
</Border>
```

Or dynamically in *C# Code*:

```
//Create a Border object
Border border = new Border();
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);
border.BorderBrush = Brushes.Black;

//Create the TextBlock object           
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Background = Brushes.White;
tb.Text = "Your Own TextBlock";

//Make the text block a child to the border
border.Child = tb;
```

Answer (score 0):

For multiline text, a label won't do. My solution is to set the Enter event on the textbox and redirect the focus elsewhere. E.g.

```
    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.anotherControl.Focus(); // Preferably a readonly control in case the user starts typing
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In WinForms, the correct method is to assign the event MouseMove and set the SelectionLength to 0.

I´ve tried here and works perfectly.

Comment: This is not a right solution. You can still select the text with a couple of clicking effort.

Comment: To fix the additional "clicking problem" that Baz said, just see my comment in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53607577/9819238).

Answer (score -1):

```
private void textBox5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.textBox5.SelectionStart = this.textBox5.Text.Length;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but the correct and simple answer is :

SelectionOpacity = 0;

this works for both TextBox and RichTextBox in WPF.

Answer (score -1):

guys!

Fell free to try this solution: first, create a derived class from original RichTextBox. In the constructor, set **Selectable** and **UserMouse** style flags:

```
public class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    public MyRichTextBox()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserMouse, true);
    }
}
```

Then, use it instead of original:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    ...
    this.richTextBox1 = new MyRichTextBox();
    ...
```

Also, you can set those behaiour flags, to avoid unnessesery user interactions:

```
this.richTextBox1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default;
this.richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
this.richTextBox1.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
```