# how to get char index of label from a position in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

Richtextbox has a function GetCharIndexFromPosition, which can be used to retrieves the index of the character nearest to the specified location.

But label has no such function, I am wondering if it is possible for it.

For example:
given the position (0,200), and we want to get the char index "d" of the label.

[image]

Comment: `GetCharIndexFromPosition` is declared in `TextBoxBase`, so I guess a brute force way to do this would be to create a text box with the same text and size as your label, and calling `GetCharIndexFromPosition` on the text box...

Comment: You can use a read-only textbox having selection disabled. Then you can use `GetCharIndexFromPosition` as suggested by Sweeper. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42391380/3110834).

Comment: Sweeper,  Reza Aghaei, Good idea, Thanks!