# How to set text to a disabled textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

i have a Textbox and some RadioButtons in C#.

Now i want to set a Text to a disabled Textbox.

What i tried:

```
private void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "****";
    TextBox1.Enabled = false;
}
```

This way i cant see the Text.

If i enable the Textbox, the TextBox shows me the String (****)

What can i do to set a Text to a disabled Textbox?

Comment: If you just want to set the `TextBox.Text` property while the textbox is disabled that should work right out of the box. Disabling the textbox just disables the textbox on your GUI. Manipulating it by code is still possible.

Comment: WinForms? WebForms? MVC? PWF?

Comment: Windows Forms, sry i forgot to say that.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        textBox1.Enabled = true;
        textBox1.Text = "*****";
        textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
        textBox1.Enabled = false;
    this.Invalidate(); //to perform form re-draw
}
```

Comment: with "ReadOnly" now i see the Text but i can click in the TextBox and its not graying out ... :(

Comment: Please refer to this [how to disable select highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256720/disable-selecting-text-in-a-textbox) for next time please be more specific

Comment: your link have nothing to do with my question For next time please be more specific ;)

Comment: Try now, its working fine on my side, i see text, and cant click

Comment: Thank your for your trying. But on my side i doesent working.

Comment: What exactly is not working ? Text is not visible ? May i see screenshot ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `PasswordChar` property based on whether or not the textbox is enabled:

```
TextBox1.PasswordChar = TextBox1.Enabled ? '\0' : '*';
```

The `\0` character will show the contents in plain text.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185747/how-can-i-unmask-password-text-box-and-mask-it-back-to-password) for similar results.

Comment: It isnt a Password TextBox. It can be also a String like "FFFF".

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is? The code I gave you will allow you to mask the text based on whether the control is enabled or not. If this isn't what you're looking for, edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: i have 10 TextBoxes ... when i checked the first CheckBox i want to disable two TextBoxes. In This TextBoxes should be a String ...

Comment: Your opening sentence was `i have a Textbox`. That's not the same as having 10 is it? I'm really not sure what you're looking for. Hopefully someone else's answer will help.

Comment: its not relevant if i have 10 or 100 TextBoxes .... 
My question was "How can i disable a TextBox with a Text" ... I dont ask anything about a PasswordChar ????