# C# - Add new Line in String Label from text document

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio

I'm making a Time Notification App with visual studio winform that will pop up a form message when the time is equal to time in my txt document. And my problem is I want to show message label in pop up form containing text in my other txt document. It's look like this.

```
int state = 1;
String[] schedule = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\loc\schedule12.txt");

Label TextBalloonLabel = new Label();

this.TextBalloonLabel.Text = dailySchedule[state];
```

In schedule String. schedule String[1] is "Good Work\nBreak Time"
And in the label it show "Good Work\nBreak Time" too. But I want to add enter in label. How to do that ??

Thanks.

Comment: This has been dicussed before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295116/add-newline-to-labels-text-at-design-time

Comment: Yes but not in runtime. I want to change it in runtime @JanMattsson

Comment: What event would happen to have the label change? If the user presses a button, you could change the label in code at that time. However, if it is a “Label” component on your form and you want to allow the users to edit this “label” at run time then it is no longer a `Label`… it’s a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 1):

You need `Environment.NewLine`.

So you can do it like this:

```
label1.Text = "test" + Environment.NewLine + "testNewLine";
```

This approach should be cross platform btw.

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
label1.Text = @"test
testNewLine";
```