# Inserting newline in .NET label

Tags: .net, winforms, user-interface, label, newline

I'd like to insert a newline into a Windows Forms text label  through the design view. Something like setting the text to be:

`Lorem ipsum \n dolor sit amet`

or

`Lorem ipsum <br/> dolor sit amet`

However, none of the above works. How can one insert a new line into a label? I have a static text that I'll be displaying, so I don't want to do it via code.

Comment: I had tried it before, but didn't work either :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Word wrap for a label in Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-a-label-in-windows-forms)*.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

When you edit the "Text" field, you should see a small arrow on the right side of that text box. If you press it, a multiline string editor should appear. Here you can insert your mulitline text.

Answer (score 20):

You can do it in the code as follows:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     label1.Text = "This is the first line\r\nAnd this is the second line.";
}
```

Comment: Question says through the design view. Nevertheless, if it would had to be done pogramatically, this would be the correct answer :D