# Insert long text to a label in runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, text, label

I am creating a label in c# (random text, just as an example):

```
Label lblText = new Label();
lblText.Text = "A computer is a general purpose device that can be programmed to carry out a set of arithmetic or logical operations. Since a sequence of operations can be readily changed, the computer can solve more than one kind of problem.";
lblText.Location = new Point(48, 95);
```

But when it is displayed I can only see: "A computer is a"

How can I display the entire text?

**EDIT:**
AutoSize worked, but it goes beyond the window's border, is there anything like "autoNewLine"? to keep the text inside the window

Comment: for word wrapping try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-label-in-winforms

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [`Label.AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the control is automatically resized to display its entire contents.
>   [...]
>   When added to a form using the designer, the default value is true. *When instantiated from code, the default value is false*.

If you also want to have word-wrapping, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-label-in-winforms).

Quoting [John Gietzen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57986/john-gietzen)'s answer:

> If you set the label to AutoSize, it will automatically grow with whatever text you put in it. (This includes vertical growth.)
>   If you want to make it word wrap at a particular width, you can set the MaximumSize property.
>
> ```
> myLabel.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 0);
> myLabel.AutoSize = true;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this property         `lblText.AutoSize = True;`  to true  because it's created at runtime and will have a false a s default value

```
   Label lblText = new Label();    
    lblText.AutoSize = True;
    lblText.Text = "A computer is a general purpose device that can be programmed to carry out a set of arithmetic or logical operations. Since a sequence of operations can be readily changed, the computer can solve more than one kind of problem.";
    lblText.Location = new Point(48, 95);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `Width` property of your `TextBox` is not high enough. Increase the `Width` of the `TextBox` and the rest of your text will automagically appear.

You can also make a TextBox auto-size to the right width by setting the `lblText.AutoSize` property to `true`.