# Resize Form To Fit Label Text

Tags: vb.net

I want to make a custom messagebox form, but there's an issue if the message is to long the text will go off screen, is there a way to word wrap it to wrap the text, and the more height the text creates the form will then size to show all the text, if you know what I mean. Not sure if this is even possible, but it has to be automatic so no manual presets, it just adapts to the text...

If anyone can help with this please let me know, thanks!

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: @SLaks WinForms, regular vb.net windows form :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is code here by ElektroStudio(s?) to do a custom messagebox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word wrap for a label in Windows Forms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-a-label-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Turn off the label's autosize property and resize the label to suit