# C# DevExpress Winforms: how to resize Labelcontrol to fit all text?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

So I have a Labelcontrol from DevExpress Winforms that needs to contain an intro-text which is undefined right now. How can I make sure that when a lot of text is added, the label will resize horizontally & vertically (as there are more lines)? If I set the Labelcontrol to maxsize length 1000px, will it start adding text on a new line after it has reached it's horizontal max?

Right now I've tried fiddling size, constrainttype, alignment options etc but can't seem to get it right.

So basically how can I make sure my small label can fit 5 or 20 lines of text & will it start a new line when it reaches the end of the label?

Comment: are the lines in your text separated by a `NewLine` or `\r\n` ?

Comment: It will not automatically adjust in height but will in width here is a relevant stackoverflow post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-a-label-in-windows-forms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word wrap for a label in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204804/word-wrap-for-a-label-in-windows-forms)